# Serialize $_POST global in wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts

I'm new here in the community, and I would like to ask if it is best practice to do this in Wordpress?

`maybe_serialize( $_POST );` and then store it to the db?

I'm a newbie in using Wordpress, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the exact functionality you should use different techniques. If you're allowing post data you would do post meta options (Get_post_meta). User data would be user_meta..

Most all the wordpress database actions are done by submitting through various types of WordPress functions. Sadly without knowing your goal I can't be more specific.

Comment: oh. cool. I'm trying to insert custom post meta_data with just one row. so I was thinking if it would be best if i just serialize the whole $_POST then insert it to the database. Is it ideal to put it that way? or is there other way to get it done? :) thanks for answering!

Comment: So you would use add_post_meta. I would create a loop that goes through an array of your post values maybe if you did that you can essentially do this in a foreach loop or something along those lines in which it would keep you from having to do maybe 20 add_post_meta lines. I'm not sure the best way to do serialize with it. I currently have not found a function that allows a multitude of key/value pairs.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta